# How do I compute $\int_0^z (\sqrt{R^2 + x^2} - x)\,dx$

Tags: integration

How do I compute:
$$
\int_0^z (\sqrt{R^2 + x^2} - x)\,dx.
$$
This document I am trying to follow has a similar integral to the one I have:

$$
\int (\sqrt{R^2 + x^2} - x) \, dx \\ =x\sqrt{R^2+x^2} + R^2\ln \left(x + \sqrt{R^2 + x^2}\right) + x_0.
$$
So I have tried a few things but have gotten no where. Does anyone know how to compute this kinda integral?

Comment: You try to evaluate a definite integral. The one you give in "the document" is an indefinite integral. What is preventing you from substituting $z$ and $0$ to it and take the difference? Or are you asking about how to do the indefinite integral?

Comment: @WeijunZhou : Maybe you should make that comment into an answer.

Comment: I am just doing bad notation because that seemed negligible in solving the actual integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_0^z (\sqrt{R^2 + x^2} - x) \, dx=\int_0^z \sqrt{R^2 + x^2} \, dx-\int_0^z x \, dx.$$

The first one is a standard $x=R \tan(u)$ substitution, and the second is easy.

Answer (score 1):

You already have the form of the indefinite integral. So you only need to take the difference.

$$\int_0^z(\sqrt{R^2+x^2}-x){\mathrm d}x=\left[x\sqrt{R^2+x^2}+R^2\ln\left.\left(x+\sqrt{R^2+x^2}\right)+x_0\right]\right|_{x=0}^{z}=z\sqrt{R^2+z^2}+R^2\ln\left(z+\sqrt{R^2+z^2}\right)+x_0-(\ln|R|+x_0)=z\sqrt{R^2+z^2}+R^2\ln\left(z+\sqrt{R^2+z^2}\right)-\ln|R|.$$

If your question is about how to evaluate the indefinite integral, see N.S.'s answer.